# $A(\pi+x)=A(x)$ and $A(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)=A(x)$ implies ? $\forall x \in R:\ (\pi+x) \in ( \alpha+\pi Z) $ and $(\frac{\pi}{2}-x) \in ( \alpha+\pi Z )$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, proof-verification

Here is exercise from french book

Let $A(x)=\cos(x).\sin(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ knowing that :

- $$A\left(\dfrac{19\pi}{3}\right)=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$$
- $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}:\quad A(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x)=A(x) \mbox{ and } A(\pi+x)=A(x). $$
- $$\forall x\notin \left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}+\pi\mathbb{Z} \right):\ A(x)=\dfrac{\tan(x)}{1+\tan^2(x)}$$

**Question**

1. $$\mbox{Solve}\quad  A(x)=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \mbox{ over } ]-\pi;\pi]$$

**Answer from the book:**
since $A\left(\dfrac{19\pi}{3}\right)=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$ then $$A(x)=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \iff A(x)=A\left(\dfrac{19\pi}{3}\right)$$

from other hand $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}:\quad A(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x)=A(x) \mbox{ and } A(\pi+x)=A(x). $$ then

$$ x=\dfrac{19\pi}{3}+k\pi \mbox{ or } x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\dfrac{19\pi}{3}+k\pi \mbox{ with } k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

**My Question:**

- I can't understand that part of solution is that true in general if we have :

$$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}: \quad A(\pi+x)=A(x) \mbox{ and } A(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x)=A(x)  \mbox{ and } A(x)=A(\alpha)$$

implies

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}:\quad  \pi+x\in \left( \alpha+\pi \mathbb{Z}\right) \mbox{ and } \dfrac{\pi}{2}-x \in \left( \alpha+\pi\mathbb{Z}\right)$$

here is source of exercise: 
[image]

**its solutions**

[image]

Comment: If I may ask : where are you located using French books ?

Comment: Which book is this from and is there an electronic form?

Answer (score 1):

$$A(x)=\sin x \cdot \cos x= \frac 12 \cdot 2 \sin x \cdot \cos x=\frac 12 \sin 2x$$
$$A(x)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$$
$$\frac 12 \sin 2x=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$$
$$\sin 2x=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$2x=(-1)^k\arcsin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right)+\pi k, k \in \mathbb Z$$
$$2x=(-1)^k \frac{\pi}{3} +\pi k, k \in \mathbb Z$$
$$x=(-1)^k \frac{\pi}{6} +\frac{\pi k}{2}, k \in \mathbb Z$$
$$x \in \left\{-\frac{5 \pi}{6}, -\frac{2 \pi}{3}, \frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{ \pi}{3} \right\}$$

**Add**

Let $T -$ period $f(x)=\sin 2x$. Then $T=\frac{2 \pi}{2}=\pi$.

Then $\forall x \in \mathbb R$
$A(x)=A(x+\pi)$

$$A(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)=\sin 2(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)=\sin (\pi-2x)=\sin 2x =A(x)$$

If $x_0 \in (\alpha + \pi \mathbb Z)$, then $\pi +x_0 \in (\alpha + \pi \mathbb Z)$

**Add2:**

Let $x_0 -$ solution of $A(x)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$ and $\forall x \in \mathbb R$: $A(x)=A(x+\pi)$. Then $x_0+\pi -$ solution of $A(x)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$.

If $x_0 \in (\alpha + \pi \mathbb Z)$ then $x_0+\pi \in (\alpha + \pi \mathbb Z)$

Similarly for $x_0 \in (\alpha + \pi \mathbb Z)$ then $\frac{\pi}{2}-x_0 \in (\alpha + \pi \mathbb Z)$

[image]

Comment: Thnaks but i'm not looking for another solution i would like to understand the proprieties that used by the book

Comment: These properties result from the periodicity of $f(x)=\sin (2x)$

Comment: i knew that but i can't see why they implies $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}:\quad  \pi+x\in \left( \alpha+\pi \mathbb{Z}\right) \mbox{ and } \dfrac{\pi}{2}-x \in \left( \alpha+\pi\mathbb{Z}\right)$

Comment: Let $T -$ period $f(x)=\sin 2x$. Then $T=\frac{2 \pi}{2}=\pi$. Then $\forall x \in \mathbb R$
$A(x)=A(x+\pi)$

If $x \in (\alpha + \pi \mathbb Z)$, then $\pi +x \in (\alpha + \pi \mathbb Z)$

Comment: My question why that $A(\pi+x)=A(x)$ and $A(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)=A(x)$ implies ? $\forall x \in R:\ (\pi+x) \in ( \alpha+\pi Z) $ and $(\frac{\pi}{2}-x) \in ( \alpha+\pi Z )$

Comment: Thank so much but why they took $x_0 \in (\alpha + \pi \mathbb Z)$

Comment: If $\alpha -$ solution of $\sin 2x=b$, then $\alpha+\pi \mathbb Z -$ solution of $\sin 2x =b$

Comment: for all  $x = \alpha + \pi .k$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ , we've
\begin{align*}
\sin [ 2 . ( \alpha + \pi . k ) ]&=\sin ( 2 . \alpha + 2 . \pi . k )\\
&=\sin ( 2 . \alpha ) \\
&=b 
\end{align*}